# GET ID from an array and POST to JOIN table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I have 3 tables which are linked with a join so the idea is I have an array as part of my form which lists out all my categories form my cat_list table:

```
  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"]; ?>" name="cat_no[$cat]"><?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>
```

So I am looping through my cat_list and showing them, if I do a var_dump on these I get this:

```
array(2) { ["cat_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["cat_title"]=> string(11) "Consumables" }
array(2) { ["cat_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["cat_title"]=> string(12) "Service Desk" }
array(2) { ["cat_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["cat_title"]=> string(14) "Solutions Team" }
array(2) { ["cat_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["cat_title"]=> string(7) "@Remote" }
array(2) { ["cat_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["cat_title"]=> string(12) "new test cat" }
```

this is great, but what I need to do is grab the ID's of whichever ones I have selected and post them in to my join table which looks like this:

```
    `cat_doc_link_table` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `link_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `link_doc_id` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=

8 ;
```

I fetchAll the cat_list to create the loop like this:

```
<?php 


try{
    // Selecting entire row from cat_list table
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT cat_id, cat_title FROM cat_list");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$cat = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


?>
```

And my action script to post looks like this:

```
<?php

include 'db_con.php';

try {

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line

$sql = "UPDATE doc_list SET doc_title = :doc_title, doc_content = :doc_content, doc_updated=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE doc_id = :doc_id";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":doc_title"=>$_POST["doc_title"],":doc_content"=>$_POST["doc_content"], ":doc_id"=> $_POST["doc_id"]));

if ($query) {
    header ('Location: ../docList.php');
}
else{
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

Comment: So what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The issue being I am really scratching my head over how I get the ID's form the array of items selected from the checkboxes, and post them into the JOIN table while also posting in the table which updates the doc at the same time. The Array will need to post the ID from whichever is selected and also associate itself with the doc id of which I am editing you see.

Comment: I don't really see where these two chunks of code connect. You're not referencing your `$cat_list` at all in the second file.

Comment: This is where I am getting confused at where this would be included - I am a point where I just need a little guidance as I am new to relational tables and updating one table while posting/updating into another

Comment: what is the connection between the categories and the doc? Is it a one-to-one relationship, or one-to-many?

Comment: It is a many to many relationship between them, so I have a doc_list table and a cat_list table and the join being the cat_doc_link_table - now this works great when viewing and I manually insert rows inside of my database gui but I seeking a way to insert the rows with checkboxes (Or am open to other options?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78114/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-james-spence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO `cat_doc_link_table`(`link_cat_id`, `link_doc_id`) VALUES";
$values = "";
$params = [];
$docId = $_POST["doc_id"];
foreach($cat_list as $cat)
{
    $values.= "(?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $cat["cat_id"];
    $params[] = $docId;
}
$values = substr($values, 0, -2);
$SQL.= $values;
$query = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
$query->execute($params);
```

You first loop through your categories there, and create a VALUES string (`$values.=`). Then, we bind our parameters to the ? marks (`$params[] = $cat["cat_id"];`). Finally, we execute the query.